# updatePanelElement.innerHTML = rendering; - Unknown Error

Tags: html, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I'm aware that the titled issue is normally caused by incorrect HTML, but for the life of me I cannot see what I have done wrong. I would greatly appreciate it if anyone would be willing to look over the code and let me know if they spot anything awry.

*I've removed the code snippet as the issue was with HTML not provided*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to figure out the issue. There was a missing span tag in the previous panel, for some reason this had no effect on that section of the page but manifested as an error on the ajaxToolKit:ModalPopupExtender. How strange.

Thank you to those who took the time to have a look over the code.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0):

if your gridview is in table then put your table inside the update panel.